# How would I use stars and bars to solve this question?

Tags: combinatorics

How would I solve the following question using stars and bars?

"Suppose you have positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$ such that

$$5a + b + c= 24$$

Determine the number of all possible ordered pairs $(a,b,c)$."

I first dealt with the constraint of $a,b,c\neq0$ by introducing $a'=a-1$, $b'=b-1$, $c'=c-1$ and thus
$$17 = 5a' + b' + c'$$
Afterwards, I noticed that $0 \leq a'\leq 3$, and since there are only $4$ cases for $a'$, I could just evaluate each case for $a'$ and use the stars and bars approach for:

$$17-5a' =b' + c'$$

I still end up with the wrong answer, however.

Am I doing something wrong, and is there a "better" or more "direct" approach to using stars and bars for this question?

Comment: Your approach looks good to me.

Answer (score 3):

Let us make $24$ stars. We want to put $2$ bars in the $23$ spaces between them in such a way that the first one separates $5a$ stars to the left. So the first bar must be put at $5$th, $10$th, $15$th or $20$th space. The number of possible spaces for the second bar is then $18$, $13$, $8$ or $3$. So the answer is $18+13+8+3=42$.

Answer (score 2):

You could leave the equations as it is over the positive integers, and use [Theorem 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#:%7E:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20combinatorial,his%20classic%20book%20on%20probability.) of stars and bars from Wikipedia, breaking it up into four cases where $5a =5,10,15,20$
which means $b+c = 19,14,9,4$

and since the formula over positive integers is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$,

answer $=18+13+8+3=42$

Comment: Of course, another way, if you know about generating functions is to find the corfficient of $x^{24}$ in the expansion of  $\frac{x^5}{1-x^5}\frac{x}{1-x}\frac{x}{1-x}$ which yields $x^7 + 2x^8 + ... 38x^{23} + 42x^{24} +...$ , giving the answer of $42$